# Do unused imports effect bundle sizes

Tags: angular

Simple question really, was just wondering does an import which is not used effect bundle sizes or does it get treeshaken out, I am building experience in this area, thanks

Comment: yeah just looking for suggestions really, i have modularized applications now which has reduced bundle sizes, i was just thinking if i forget to remove an unused import will it stay in there as applications starting to get quote large now

Answer (score 2):

Yes, all imports have impact on bundle sizes.

An other tip :

When you import something try to do like this :

```
import last from 'lodash/last'
```

and not like this :

```
import { last } from 'lodash'
```

In the first case you just import the part of package you will use.

In the second case, you import all of package.

Comment: thanks was looking from perspective of if that then goes unused does it get shaken out, or not included at all,